# Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit GTK themes and Icon themese not working properly

Tags: 14.04, dell, themes, icons, gtk

I have Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit installed on two separate computers (Dell XPS L502X and Dell Latitude E5440). The themes I installed either by extracting compressed files or using the `apt-get` package manager worked flawlessly after a fresh install of the OS on Dell XPS L502X; however this is not the case on Dell Latitude E5440? What may be the reason behind it?

In order to copy the themes and icons from XPS to Latitude I used a memory stick and copied the contents of `/usr/share/icons` and `/usr/share/themes` directories from the computer which had the themes and icons installed(being XPS in this case). Later I plugged the flash drive into the Latitude and tried changing themes. In order to be able to set the themes easily I installed `Ubuntu Tweak` from a PPA and I noticed that when I first launched `Ubuntu Tweak` it failed to show the themes apart from the cursor ones. The `GTK` themes were not shown for example, I thought this might have something to do with file permissions or something so I decided to find which themes can be installed from the repository and installed them accordingly. After this step `GTK` and `icon` themes showed up in the `Ubuntu Tweak Tool`, but when changed into a theme which was not supplied with Vanilla Ubuntu I noticed that there were inconsistencies in color etc. and the theme just did not display properly and for the icon theme not all icons were changes as was the case with XPS. I think I made a blunder here but could not figure out how to remedy it? Any assistance suggestion would be nice.

P.S : The cursor themes work fine no problems with them.

Comment: Maybe obvious, but did you ensure the permissions are set right on your theme files (ie are the same as the permissions a theme deb will set) ?

Comment: @alci How can I be sure of that?

Comment: @alci Actually I tried it for a particular theme I have two computers side by side right now adjusted them to have the same permissions(for a particular theme at one time) but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my mistake was to move the themes installed via `PPA` directly over to the other computer, thinking that it will work since all themes are constrained to the directories `/usr/share/icons/` and `/usr/share/themes` as far as I understood from this experience it is not the case. Anyways I deleted nearly everything in these folders and hope to replace the default Ubuntu 14.04 themes as well where can I find them?